# Pass a JavaScript hash as parameter to a jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought it would be handy if I define my function, so that I can pass hashes to it. With the idea that later on when I extend my code I can easily pass more variables without having to change my other code that also executing this code.

Now I made an example, but somehow it won't work:

```
function test(data){
    if(data.id){
        $('body').append($('<p/>',{text: "hallo"});
    }
};

test({id: 5, text: 4});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HQ9P2/

What do I do wrong? And is this the right way to avoid cohesion in my code?

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis, open the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not like this answer but you're missing a ")"

```
$('body').append($('<p/>',{text: "hallo"})); <--- notice
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HQ9P2/1/